# docusign PDF validation issue, is there documentation available?

Tags: pdf, docusignapi, fdf

We have some code which is generating a data filled PDF (fdf) file from an excel spreadsheet which is then being sent to docusign in our test environment.

Some of these work, and some come back with an error "PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED".

We have narrowed it down to the PDF document itself, and have watered down the original template to contain just four fields. We have watered down our excel spreadsheet to four basic fields using (for example) "a,1,a,2" for one input and "aa,1,a,2" as another, however one will consistently work and one will consistently fail.

Viewing the generated PDF's in a local PDF viewer (Adobe and PDF XChange Editor) the document appears fine, viewing the documents side by side in a hex/diff editor (WinMerge) shows minor differences in the streams being sent (as expected).

Is there any documentation on what validation is being performed on the PDF so we can emulate this locally and make sure our PDF's are valid before sending to the docusign API?

Thanks

[Template](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fYm45TVVBVExlcmc)

Comment: While I don't know whether there is any documentation like you look for, but if you shared your two sample PDFs, others might investigate them, too.

Comment: [Working FDF source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fempjYWdndTBuRTg)   [Working PDF output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fR1VvRnBkUWNYQVk)  [Non-working FDF source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fcW1PVWdIYjRxcjg) [Non working PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fRHc2YTBDSHBkcHM)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added above ...

Comment: I had a look at the documents but at first glance could find nothing fishy. Probably someone more into docusign could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to successfully create an envelope with the Documents you have provided.

See [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/72c93a1838aecfe867b6c05445fb38d6) for the complete [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request that I have used

I have used these documents that you have provided

- [Working PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fR1VvRnBkUWNYQVk)
- [Non Working PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Bxyfpfrk_fRHc2YTBDSHBkcHM)

Comment: Thanks, it ended up being an issue with the code I was supplied, which was creating invalid data from the PDF, not with the docusign API ... but I appreciate your answer as it clarified another issue I was having ...